# Accessing memory stick wirelessly through vsftpd + WinSCP

Tags: vsftpd

To transfer files between a Windows 10 desktop and Linux laptop wirelessly using FTP, I installed vsftpd as the FTP server on the laptop and WinSCP as the FTP client on the desktop, and configured the /etc/vsftpd.conf such that I'm only able to reach the contents of the home user on the laptop.
This is working fine.

When I plug a memory stick into the laptop, it becomes accessible there.

But how can the stick be made accessible from the Windows desktop WinSCP as well?

Comment: The stick's filesystem must be mounted in a place that is reachable via FTP. When you plug it in, it is probably mounted automatically under a directory like `/media`. Unmount it and mount it again somewhere under the user's home directory.

Comment: I managed to do that manually, but this needs to be done automagically each time I insert the stick. Will try to figure this out using a script or using the method suggested by Archemar.

Answer (score 0):

depending on distribution, removable device pluged in by `user` are mounted on

```
/media/user/LABEL
```

where `LABEL` is either explicit device label (if set), os some guess.

either

- use explicit label (if always working with same stick),
- include `/media/user` in vsftpd's rule (and remote user will have access to all locally plugged devices)